# How benchmark server with load balancer

Tags: benchmark

Hey I have four computers(with linux):

- two with mediawiki(mirror, both connected to one db)
- one with mysql
- one server(DHCP,DNS etc)

I configured on my server load balancer and now hen I type in browser **name.local** for example I get one of my mediawiki servers. I press f5 really fast and then I see in **top** command both computers are being loaded but not much. I used tool ab (apache benchamrk) but if I run it always is connected to one server never alternately.

I use this settings:

```
ab -n 100 -c 10 http://name.local/
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use some sort of stress-testing apps, like [LOIC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Low_Orbit_Ion_Cannon) to send multiple requests via different protocols, to different ports, with specified frequency to the specified hostname/IP-address.

[Here](http://www.opensourcetesting.org/performance.php) you can find a bunch of different stress testing tools which fit your needs.